# Laravel project temporary access needs cPanel name

Tags: php, laravel, url, dns, cpanel

I need to show to my client the progress of a project that is already in the shared host.

In development, acessing just /localhost/ worked to me, but now that I've sent the files to the host (cPanel), it's breaking in some cases because I need to use the /~cpanelname in the IP. Is there a way to add this /~cpanelname to every URL? After the deployment and insertion of a domain, it will need to be removed also.

The problem basically is:
When I have an image, the src is:
[IP]/img/img.jpg

When it needs to be [IP]/~cpanelname/img/img.jpg

A link href that is /about needs to be /~cpanelname/about

Can you guys help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a domain for it? I tend to use a subdomain for my clients like `staging.example.com`

Comment: I have tested with a subdomain but it just work if I go to subdomain.domain.com/~cpanelname too. Same problem with ~cpanelname

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `asset()`, `route()`, `url()` etc. [helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers) to construct all of your links and file references.

If you've done that correctly, you can then change the base URL for all URLs just by changing the `config/app.php` file's `url` parameter (typically by changing `APP_URL` in `.env`).